# How to parallelize calculations for neural networks?

Tags: python, neural-network

**Which is the best design to parallelize calculations to improve the speed of a set of neural networks ?**

1/ Do one’s have to slice the raw data set and share it between different neural networks ?

In this case, I think every neural network won’t have the whole picture of the dataset and this design would lead to a poor learning.

2/ Or do one’s have to make every neural network to work on the whole data set ?

In this case, I don’t see the improvement compared to a single neural network making the whole study.
In addition I think also that the treatment time won’t be improve.

So I am thinking on a multiprocessing architecture but I don’t know the libraries to use nor how to make that possible.

These are ways I have considered, but generally the question is how to organize the **general design** in order to improve time treatment ?

I would very appreciate to have a sample of organized parallelized architecture written in Python followed by the theorical approach if possible.

Comment: People normally use GPUs to parallelize the solver which generally shortens training time significantly. The question really is what are you trying to parallelize? There is not much reason to have more than 1 neural net on one dataset UNLESS you are trying to do parameter tuning which then simply means just run the same training program with slightly diffrent parameters. You could do this in multiprocessing but why make it complicated when you can just launch n instances. Have a look at keras and check out how CUDA works.